# Setting up LiveData observer in custom view without LifecycleOwner

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying out the new Android Architecture components and have run into a road block when trying to use the MVVM model for a custom view.

Essentially I have created a custom view to encapsulate a common UI and it's respective logic to use throughout the app. I can set up the ViewModel in the custom view but then I'd have to either use `observeForever()` or manually set a `LifecycleOwner` in the custom view like below but neither seem correct.

### Option 1) Using `observeForever()`

**Activity**

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var myCustomView : CustomView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        myCustomView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view)
        myCustomView.onAttach()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        myCustomView.onDetach()
    }
}
```

**Custom View**

```
class (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(context,attrs){

    private val viewModel = CustomViewModel()

    fun onAttach() {
        viewModel.state.observeForever{ myObserver }
    }

    fun onDetach() {
        viewModel.state.removeObserver{ myObserver }
    }
}
```

### Option 2) Setting lifecycleOwner from Activity`

**Activity**

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var myCustomView : CustomView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        myCustomView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view)
        myCustomView.setLifeCycleOwner(this)
    }
}
```

**Custom View**

```
class (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(context,attrs){

    private val viewModel = CustomViewModel()

    fun setLifecycleOwner(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner) {
        viewModel.state.observe(lifecycleOwner)
    }
}
```

Am I just misusing the patterns and components? I feel like there should be a cleaner way to compose complex views from multiple sub-views without tying them to the Activity/Fragment

Comment: Why you don't use  `observeForever(observer)` instead? It does not require a _LifeCycleOwner_ and you can remove Observer in `onDetachedFromWindow()`

Answer (score 6):

**1 Option** - 
With good intention, you still have to do some manual work - like, calling `onAttach`\ `onDetach` Main purpose of Architecture components is to prevent doing this.

**2 Option** - 
In my opinion is better, but I would say it's a bit wrong to bind your logic around `ViewModel` and `View`. I believe you can do same logic inside `Activity/Fragment` without passing ViewModel and `LifecycleOwner` to `CustomView`. Single method `updateData` is enough for this purpose.

So, in this particular case, I would say it's overuse of Architecture Components.

Comment: For people who like me use Custom Views instead of Fragments this is a problem. I will go with Option 1 as there is no way I am going back to Fragments and their LOL lifecycles.

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't make sense to manage the lifecycle of the the view manually by passing some reference of the activity to the views and calling onAttach/onDetach, when we already have the context provided when that view is created.

I have a fragment in a NavigationView that has other fragments in a view pager, more like a nested fragment hierarchy scenario.

I have some custom views in these top-level fragments, when the custom view is directly in the top fragment, I can get an observer like this

```
viewModel.itemLiveData.observe((context as ContextWrapper).baseContext as LifecycleOwner,
   binding.item.text = "some text from view model"         
}
```

when I have the custom view as a direct child of an activity I set it up directly as

```
viewModel.itemLiveData.observe(context as LifecycleOwner,
   binding.item.text = "some text from view model"         
}
```

in these activities, if I have a fragment and it has some custom view and I use the 2nd approach, I get a ClassCastException(), and I have to reuse these custom views in different places, both activities, and fragments (that's the idea of having a custom view)

so i wrote an extension function to set the LifeCycleOwner

```
fun Context.getLifecycleOwner(): LifecycleOwner {
    return try {
        this as LifecycleOwner
    } catch (exception: ClassCastException) {
        (this as ContextWrapper).baseContext as LifecycleOwner
    }
}
```

now i simply set it everywhere as

```
viewModel.itemLiveData.observe(context.getLifecycleOwner(),
   binding.item.text = "some text from view model"         
}
```

Comment: a Fragment can have have two lifecycle owners: of fragment itself or of view of fragment (`viewLifecycleOwner`). In our case we need to get `viewLifecycleOwner` somehow if custom view was inflated in fragment