# Live data in custom class view

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to observe LiveData in custom class view? in fragments im using getViewLifecycleOwner, but what to do in a customview? Thank you very much for help.

Comment: You can use `observeForever` in your custom view  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335464/setting-up-livedata-observer-in-custom-view-without-lifecycleowner

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your custom object in liveData instance.

```
MutableLiveData <CustomObject> mLiveObject = new MutableLiveData<CustomObject>();
```

Next you have to post changes to this object using post method.

```
mLiveObject.postValue(mCustomObject);
```

Lastly you have to observe it for changes.

```
mLiveObject .observe(getActivity(), new Observer<CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(CustomObject customObject) {
            // do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: What if postValue is in MainActivity?

Comment: Doesn't really matter. You want to observe it in child fragment?

Comment: I want observe this in custom class extends LinearLayout. Is it possible ?

Comment: I believe it would be possible but live date is not supposed to be used in this way.

Comment: Please share your use-case. It might help the community to suggest a better solution